# Combinations With Repetition Intuition

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> How many ways are there to choose a 5-letter “words” from the 26-letter English
>   alphabet with repeated letters allowed, but words that are anagrams are considered the same? The words
>   need not be English language words.

I believe my intuition is correct here, but upon calculating the expression, it doesn't equal to an integer.

First we have to find all 5 letter "words" with repeating characters allowed. So we have:

$26^5$

Because we have $26$ choices for each of the slots for a 5 letter word.

Next, we divide by $5!$ because we over-counted the number of words we want which excludes anagrams, and there are $5!$ ways to arrange the letters of the word.

Where am I going wrong here?
I was told that this was an application of combinations with repetition, but I don't understand why my approach is not correct.

Comment: Consider the word aaaaa. Did you really count it $5!$ times?

Comment: @eranreches No, looks like I didn't. Something that confuses me about counting like this is assuming that each of the same characters are considered distinct, where there are $5!$ "aaaaa" words

Comment: Without using the combinations with repetitions formula, how can I think about this in terms of the multiplication principle?

Comment: Divide into cases. Words with $5$ **different** letters repeat $5!$ times in your counting.  Words with $4$ different letters repeat $5!/2!$ times ($5!$ options to reorder the word, divided by the cases of reordering the same two letters which does not affect the word). Can you continue?

Comment: Words with 3 different letters repeat $5!/3!$ times. Words with 2 different letters repeat $5!/4!$ times. Words with 1 different letter repeat $5!/5!$ times. Am I correct?

Comment: Words with one letter repeats $5!/5!=1$ times, makes sense, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm a little lost however on putting this all together to get the total number of 5 letter words.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94892/discussion-between-eranreches-and-jd94).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us count the different possibilities.

- If the word has $5$ different letters, then it is just $26$-choose-$5$ or $\binom{26}{5}$.
- If the word has $4$ different letters, with $1$ that is repeated, then first find the number of sets with $4$ different letters which is $\binom{26}{4}$, and now you have $4$ options to choose which letter to duplicate twice. This gives $4\binom{26}{4}$.
- If the word has $3$ different letters, you again get all the $\binom{26}{3}$ sets of $3$ different letters. Now you have two options: either you duplicate one of the three letters $3$ times - $3$ options for that, or you choose $2$ letters and duplicate each one twice - again $3$ options. In total this gives $6\binom{26}{3}$.
- If the word has $2$ different letters, you get as usual the $\binom{26}{2}$ sets of $2$ different letters and duplicate either one of the letters $4$ times - $2$ options; or duplicate one letter $2$ times, and the other $3$ times - again $2$ options. In total this is $4\binom{26}{2}$.
- Finally, if the word has just $1$ distinct letter you have $\binom{26}{1}$ options.

In total the number of different words satisfying your criterion is (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binom(26,5)%2B4*binom(26,4)%2B6*binom(26,3)%2B4*binom(26,2)%2Bbinom(26,1)))

$$N=\binom{26}{5}+4\binom{26}{4}+6\binom{26}{3}+4\binom{26}{2}+\binom{26}{1}=142\:506$$

---

Let me now suggest a way to check this via a computer. Assign a number $1-26$ to each letter in the alphabet. Convince yourself that we are looking for the number of tuples $\left(i,j,k,l,m\right)$ such that $i\leq j\leq k\leq l\leq m$. In other words, if we organize the letters in ascending order we don't overcount. The number of such tuples is

$$N=\sum_{1\leq i\leq j\leq k\leq l\leq m\leq26}1=\sum_{i=1}^{26}\sum_{j=i}^{26}\sum_{k=j}^{26}\sum_{l=k}^{26}\sum_{m=l}^{26}1=142\:506$$

according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(i%3D1%20to%2026)sum(j%3Di%20to%2026)sum(k%3Dj%20to%2026)sum(l%3Dk%20to%2026)sum(m%3Dl%20to%2026)%201), confirming our previous result.

Comment: Found a much shorter answer than mine https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109666/how-many-10-letter-words-can-we-find-such-that-none-of-them-are-anagrams. In your case this is $\binom{5+26-1}{5}=142\:506$ as before (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binom(5%2B26-1,5)&t=crmtb01).